# How to get divs to respond to screen resizing like imgs?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

In REACT, I have three divs that I would like to position side by side, separated by a small margin, and horizontally centered on the screen.

When the screen width becomes too small, I would like the right-most div to move below the first two divs, but still be horizontally centered.

When the screen becomes even smaller, I would like all three divs to be in a column in the center of the screen.

This is easy to achieve with images:

Html (the REACT flavor of html):

```
<div id='container'>
    <img src={image}/>
    <img src={image}/>
    <img src={image}/>
<div/>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    text-align: center;
}
```

How can this be done with objects that are not imgs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stack overflow, I think what you're looking for is css flexbox https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox.

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.childClass { // you would need to add a className to the child divs
  width: // add the width of your divs here, this will force them to wrap
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

I think that should do it, but I highly encourage you to read https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ - it's one of the best resources on using flexbox for layouts

Answer (score 0):

```css
//use flexbox for easy structuring html elements
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.first {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.second {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.third {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.flex-item {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first flex-item">First div</div>
  <div class="second flex-item">Second div</div>
  <div class="third flex-item">Third div</div>
</div>
```

for more info on flexbox visit here : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/